# Android studio download dependency failed,Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: android, react-native

I have configured the proxy, and the proxy is also configured in the IDE, and I tested the link to the jar. He also works
with it, but I don’t know why it is not downloaded.

```
org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2-sources.jar'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawHead(HttpClientHelper.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHead(HttpClientHelper.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.getMetaData(HttpResourceAccessor.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.getMetaData(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.getMetaData(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$1.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$1.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:350)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:340)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:120)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.getMetaData(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.staticResourceExists(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.artifactExists(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.findOptionalArtifacts(ExternalResourceResolver.java:279)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver$MavenRemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveSourceArtifacts(MavenResolver.java:333)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver$MavenRemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveSourceArtifacts(MavenResolver.java:309)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$AbstractRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifactsWithType(ExternalResourceResolver.java:402)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifactsWithType(ExternalResourceResolver.java:472)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifactsWithType(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:387)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifactsWithType(BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository$CachedAccess.resolveArtifactsWithType(InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifactsWithType(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.resolveArtifactsWithType(RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingArtifactResolver.resolveArtifactsWithType(ErrorHandlingArtifactResolver.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.query.DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.addArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.java:158)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.query.DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.buildComponentResult(DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.java:151)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.query.DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.access$100(DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.query.DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery$1.create(DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.query.DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery$1.create(DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.java:116)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:222)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:152)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.query.DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.execute(DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.DependencyResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(DependencyResolverImpl.java:207)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.DependencyResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(DependencyResolverImpl.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.builder.ModelBuildScriptClasspathBuilderImpl.buildAll(ModelBuildScriptClasspathBuilderImpl.java:89)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder.buildAll(ExtraModelBuilder.java:67)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:79)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:61)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.BuildControllerAdapter.getModel(BuildControllerAdapter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractBuildController.findModel(AbstractBuildController.java:39)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addExtraProject(ProjectImportAction.java:123)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:76)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.buildResult(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:79)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.access$000(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$1.buildFinished(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:371)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:353)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManagerEventBroadcastListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:341)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManagerEventBroadcastListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:148)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
```

configure

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation com.android.support:appcompat- 
v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
api "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
api "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
```

with

```
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
```

Also can you post your **android/build.gradle** and **gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties?**

Answer (score 0):

The read timeout happened when your proxy configuration is not valid. For testing the proxy you can use this way:

1. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>:
2. Search for HTTP proxy.
3. Make sure you have a valid configuration on it (HTTP or SOCKS) then Press Check connection and test it out using google.com.

If the result was successful check the `gradle.properties` inside your project which must be like this:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 (your proxy ip)
systemProp.http.proxyPort=1080 (your proxy port)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue when was adding Google services
Android Studio was failing to download classpath `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4`

Solved this issue by placing `google()` as first line in

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()    // must be first
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()    //must be first
        jcenter()
    }
}
```